# Bootloader loading image file

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I need some help understanding the logic for loading the kernel with BrokenThorn's bootloader.

The code:

```
LOAD_IMAGE:

          mov     ax, WORD [cluster]                  ; cluster to read
          pop     bx                                  ; buffer to read into
          call    ClusterLBA                          ; convert cluster to LBA
          ;xor     cx, cx
          ;mov     cl, BYTE [bpbSectorsPerCluster]     ; sectors to read (commenting out has same result?
          call    ReadSectors                          ;(ES:BX from above)
          push    bx

     ; compute next cluster

          mov     ax, WORD [cluster]                  ; identify current cluster
          mov     cx, ax                              ; copy current cluster
          mov     dx, ax                              ; copy current cluster
          shr     dx, 0x0001                          ; divide by two
          add     cx, dx                              ; sum for (3/2)
          mov     bx, 0x0200                          ; location of FAT in memory
          add     bx, cx                              ; index into FAT
          mov     dx, WORD [bx]                       ; read two bytes from FAT
          test    ax, 0x0001
          jnz     .ODD_CLUSTER

     .EVEN_CLUSTER:

          and     dx, 0000111111111111b               ; take low twelve bits
         jmp     .DONE

     .ODD_CLUSTER:

          shr     dx, 0x0004                          ; take high twelve bits

     .DONE:

          mov     WORD [cluster], dx                  ; store new cluster
          cmp     dx, 0x0FF0                          ; test for end of file
          jb     LOAD_IMAGE

     DONE:

          mov     si, msgCRLF
          call    Print
          push    WORD 0x0050
          push    WORD 0x0000
          retf
```

Why do I need to convert CHS to LBA? In the function, it seems as though the LBA is stored in the AX register. But it isn't being used in `ReadSectors`? And afterwards, the current cluster is then copied into AX.

```
ClusterLBA:
          sub     ax, 0x0002                          ; zero base cluster number
          xor     cx, cx
          mov     cl, BYTE [bpbSectorsPerCluster]     ; convert byte to word
          mul     cx
          add     ax, WORD [datasector]               ; base data sector

          ret
```

Also, the bootloader loads the kernel into memory location 0x0050:0x0000

Why can I not `jmp 0x0050:0x0000` and start execution of code? What does

`push WORD 0x0050
 push WORD 0x0000`

do? This wasn't explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why do I need to convert CHS to LBA?**

You don't, and the code isn't doing that anywhere I can see. I assume what the code does do is convert a (FAT) "cluster number" into an LBA number. Note that the FAT file system uses clusters (which may be 512 bytes, 1024 bytes, ...) where clusters numbers are relative to the start of the partition (and not the start of the disk).

**In the function, it seems as though the LBA is stored in the AX register. But it isn't being used in ReadSectors?**

You didn't post the code for `ReadSectors` and didn't provide a link to wherever that code might be. I can only assume that you're wrong and that `ReadSectors` does use the LBA in AX (e.g. a quick LBA to CHS conversion immediately before using `int0x13` to load the sector/s).

**Why can I not jmp 0x0050:0x0000 and start execution of code?**

You can.

Sadly, a lot of people that write assembly language code are not assembly language programmers (e.g. they might be C programmers who know a little bit of assembly language). More sadly, some crusty old assemblers aren't very good and make it difficult for people to figure out how to do a far jump. Basically, the "push; push; retf" is there because whoever wrote it didn't or couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

ClusterLBA converts cluster# (in AX) to sector# (in AX) to be able to read these sectors via int 13h.
ReadSectors seems to take AX, ES:BX as parameters.
Push, push, retf is equivalent to jmp far.  Both variants are 5 bytes long.  No difference.